# Why doesn't my gcc compiler recognize the bzip2 functions, yet allows me to include the library they belong to?

Tags: c, gcc, msys, pacman-package-manager

I'm writing a file parser in C using gcc on Windows using MSYS2.

Using pacman I've downloaded [the required libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62225237/8772751) for using [libbzip2](https://www.sourceware.org/bzip2/manual/manual.html#libprog).

For some reason, I can include the bzlib.h file and use the structures it contains, but not its functions.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <bzlib.h>

void init_decompress_stream(bz_stream *stream, char *next_in, unsigned int avail_in, char *next_out, unsigned int avail_out);

int main(){
  // Open FILE
  FILE *ptr;
  ptr = fopen("example.bin", "rb");

  // Read Metadata
  int metadata[10];
  fread(metadata, sizeof(int), 10, ptr);

  // Init stream
  bz_stream *stream;
  unsigned int avail_in = metadata[0] * sizeof(char);
  unsigned int avail_out = metadata[1] * sizeof(int);
  char *compressed_data = malloc(avail_in);
  char *data = malloc(avail_out);

  // Read data
  fread(compressed_data, 1, avail_in, ptr);
  init_decompress_stream(stream, compressed_data, avail_in, data, avail_out);

  // Decompress data -- COMPILES FINE UNTIL HERE --
  int bz_result = BZ2_bzDecompressInit(stream, 0, 0);
}

void init_decompress_stream(bz_stream *stream, char *next_in, unsigned int avail_in, char *next_out, unsigned int avail_out){
  stream->next_in = next_in;
  stream->avail_in = avail_in;
  stream->next_out = next_out;
  stream->avail_out = avail_out;
}
```

This all compiles fine until the last line of main: `int bz_result = BZ2_bzDecompressInit(stream, 0, 0);`

when I compile using at which point I get the error:

`C:/msys64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Local\Temp\cct30tb5.o:test.c(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzDecompressInit'`

`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

While troubleshooting I've used three different compile commands:

`gcc test.c` This compiles `#include <bzlib.h>` and `bz_stream *stream;` just fine until the last line.

`gcc test.c -L/usr/lib/libbz2.a` this performs same as above.

`gcc test.c -libbz2` this one cannot find -libbz2

I'm totally perplexed as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In gcc, `-L` add a directory to the library search path, and `-l` specifies a library to load (using the search path to find it).

Hence you probably need something like:

```
gcc test.c -L /usr/lib -l bz2
```

I'd be surprised if `/usr/lib` wasn't already on the library path but you may want to specify it just in case. And the toolchain is smart enough to prefix your library names with `lib` and suffix them with extensions as needed.

You should be aware that `gcc test.c -libbz2` is *probably* equivalent to `gcc test.c -l ibbz2` which is going to be looking for `ibbz2`, *not* what you wanted.